# How to draw dashed(-) radius on google maps swift?

Tags: google-maps, swift3

[image]

I'm struggling to get dashed radius on google maps. Can anyone please help?. I need an output like attached image.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Directly on circle is not possible

You could draw a polyline based on circle

```
 var myCicle = new google.maps.Polyline({
               path: drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng( 46.0,11.0), 50, 1),
               strokeOpacity: 0,
               icons: [{
                 icon: lineSymbol,
                 offset: '0',
                 repeat: '15px'
               }],
               strokeWeight: 1,
               fillColor: "#FFFF00",
               fillOpacity: 0.15,
               map:map
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

With GMSCircle its not possible, you have to draw a polyline based on a circle.

With GMSGeometryOffset you can generate an offset to your location.
360/6 = 60 for less detail an efficiency.

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()

for i in 0...60 {
    let offsetLocation = GMSGeometryOffset(location.coordinate, circleRadius, CLLocationDirection(i*6))
    path.add(offsetLocation)
}
let length: [NSNumber] = [10, 10]
let circle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
let styles = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.clear), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.red)]

circle.spans = GMSStyleSpans(circle.path!, styles, length, GMSLengthKind.rhumb)
circle.strokeWidth = 1.0
circle.map = mapView
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.